# iTunes download all songs at once

Tags: itunes, music

I can't find any way to download all my purchased songs at once.

I have a list of 100+ albums, so clicking on Downlod for each album is not viable.

I was hoping to show Account -> Purchased -> Not in my library. and select all albums and then download all at once, but I'm out of ideas.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can download an entire playlist with one click.

[image]

I just noticed that In your library: You can sort your music by "in the cloud" (the cloud logo). When you add the music which is only in the cloud to a playlist, iTunes will automatically download your added songs :-)

Comment: Even nicer is a smart playlist that updates. If you have a lot of music, you might need to come back and kick off a few downloads until it all arrives to the local storage.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you get to the above location?